# Applying cluster indexing to a view in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, left-join

I have a view which queries around 1+ million rows and takes around 10-15 minutes to finish its execution,I want to provide cluster indexing to it so that it exists in physical schema and takes less time to load, but there are a number of constraints in order to provide cluster indexing i.e. only INNER JOIN are allowed and No subqueries should be present in views defination how do I replace the LEFT JOIN present in this view with INNER JOIN and how do I eliminate subqueries from this views defination so that cluster indexing can be applied to it.

```
CREATE view [dbo].[FTM_ProfileDetailsView] with SCHEMABINDING as

    select FTM.Id
    , FTM.EmployeeId
    , FTM.CustomerId
    , FTM.AbsenceFirstDate
    , FTM.BackgroundHistory
    , FTM.BackgroundHistoryComments
    , FTM.IsEmployeeAbsent,FTM.ServiceId
    , Case When isnull(FTM.IsSelfManagement,'')='' THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE FTM.IsSelfManagement END as IsSelfManagement
    , PR.ServiceLineId,FTM.ProfileId,PR.StatusId,Status.Status as StatusName
    , PR.ReasonID
    , PR.ModifiedDate
    , PR.WithdrawnReason
    , PR.CreatedBy
    , PR.CreatedDate
    , PR.IsActive 
    , mgrs.usernames as LineManagers
    , cust.CustomerName
    , ltrim(rtrim( emp.EmployeeTitle+' '+ emp.FirstName+' '+ emp.Surname)) as EmployeeFullName
    , FTM.ProfileManagerId
    , FTM.IsProfileManagement
    , AM.MonitoringChecks
    , AM.Frequency
    , AM.ProfileManagerNotes
    , AM.TaskDateAndTime
    , FTM.ProfileManagementCriteriaId
    ,cast(case when PR.StatusId = 13 then 1 else 0 end as bit) as IsActiveMonitoring
    , CustServ.CustomerServiceName
    , BU.Name as BusinessUnit
    , emp.DASID
    , emp.DateOfBirth as EmployeeDOB
    , addr.PostCode
    , coninfo.Email
    , (select top 1
      StatusId from dbo.PR_Profileintervention ProfileInt
      where ProfileInt.ProfileId=FTM.Profileid
      order by ProfileInt.Id desc) as LatestInterventionStatusId
    , (select name from dbo.FTM_Intervention Intr
      where Intr.Id=(select top 1 InterventionId from dbo.PR_Profileintervention ProfileInt
      where ProfileInt.ProfileId=FTM.Profileid 
      order by ProfileInt.Id desc))
      as LatestInterventionName  from FTM_Profile FTM

    LEFT JOIN   dbo.ProfileManagersView mgrs ON mgrs.ProfileID = FTM.ProfileID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customer cust on cust.Id= FTM.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Employee emp on emp.Id = FTM.EmployeeId
    INNER JOIN dbo.PR_Profile PR on PR.Profileid=FTM.ProfileId
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.BusinessUnit BU on BU.Id=PR.BUId
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.PR_dv_Status [Status] on [Status].Id = PR.StatusId
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.CM_ActiveMonitoringDetails AM on AM.ProfileId = PR.Profileid
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.FTM_CustomerServiceMapping CustServ on CustServ.ServiceId = FTM.ServiceId and CustServ.CustomerId = FTM.CustomerId
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.contact con on con.Id = emp.ContactID
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.address addr on addr.Id = con.HomeAddressId
    LEFT JOIN   dbo.contactinfo coninfo on coninfo.Id = con.ContactInfoId
```

Comment: [Start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have read it , my problem is how to overcome these limitations in my views defination.

Comment: There's no magic "switch `X` for `Y` and switch `W` for `Z`" to overcome these limitations. If there were, *why would the product not do them for you automatically*? In general, if the original query is sensibly constructed but is hitting a limitation, any sane re-write of the query will hit the same or other limitations.

Comment: I am almost sure your query will be substantially faster without subqueries. Can you check it?

Comment: You can't change left joins to inner joins or the results set will be different. You are never going to be able to index this view. However by getting rid of the correlated subqueries (and you should never again write one as they are performance killers, they are essentially row-by-row cursors) , your performance may be just fine using the indexes on the underlying tables.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion. Can you try and change your query so the sub -queries in the SELECT are placed in CROSS APPLYs?

So something along the lines of this in your WHERE clause:

```
CROSS APPLY (  
                select top 1 StatusId AS LatestInterventionStatusId
                from dbo.PR_Profileintervention ProfileInt
                where ProfileInt.ProfileId=FTM.Profileid
                order by ProfileInt.Id desc

            ) LatestInterventionStatusId

CROSS APPLY (
                select name AS LatestInterventionName
                from dbo.FTM_Intervention Intr
                where Intr.Id=(select top 1 InterventionId 
                               from dbo.PR_Profileintervention ProfileInt
                               where ProfileInt.ProfileId=FTM.Profileid 
                               order by ProfileInt.Id desc)
             )LatestInterventionName
```

And then of course change the column names in the SELECT to something like this:

```
, LatestInterventionStatusId.LatestInterventionStatusId
, LatestInterventionName.LatestInterventionName
```

Give this a go and let me know if it makes a different.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you didn't give me an answer on my question, but the subqueries should be changed. Try to use this instead the two subqueries:

```
/*
...
, emp.DateOfBirth as EmployeeDOB
, addr.PostCode
, coninfo.Email
*/
, p.StatusId as LatestInterventionStatusId
, p.name     as LatestInterventionName  

from FTM_Profile FTM

OUTER APPLY (
    select TOP 1 Intr.name, ProfileInt.StatusId
    from dbo.PR_Profileintervention ProfileInt
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FTM_Intervention Intr ON Intr.Id = ProfileInt.InterventionId
    where ProfileInt.ProfileId = FTM.Profileid 
    order by ProfileInt.Id desc
) p
/*
LEFT JOIN   dbo.ProfileManagersView mgrs ON mgrs.ProfileID = FTM.ProfileID
INNER JOIN dbo.Customer cust on cust.Id= FTM.CustomerId
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee emp on emp.Id = FTM.EmployeeId
...
*/
```